# How to source annotate python when using qcachegrind to process profilestats output

Tags: python, python-2.7, profiling, kcachegrind, profilestats

[Kcachegrind](http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net/html/Home.html) serves as a wonderful utility to visually represent the hotspot to the source line level when profiling code. I found it pretty useful when micro optimizing my C++ code base. 
For my latest python project I started using Kcachegrind  to process the output from [profilestats](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/profilestats). [Kcachegrind](http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net/html/Home.html) is a linux only utility but various unofficial ports are available and one I am using is [qcachegrind](http://sourceforge.net/projects/qcachegrindwin/). 
Generally it works to a large extent and suffices for most issues except I am having a hard time getting the source annotation work.

**On the source Tab I am being greeted with the familiar source missing message**

```
There is no source available for the following function:
   'main C:\Projects\module\src\source.py:397'
This is because no debug information is present
Recompile source and redo the profile run.
The function is located in the ELF Object:
  '(unknown)'
```

**Using the option**

```
Settings -> Configure -> Source Annotation
```

and adding the Source Base Directory was not useful.

I have a feeling that the utility wants an ELF Object which is not relevant for Python. Any help in this regard would be useful.

**Relevant Information:**

- Python 2.7
- profilestats (2.0)
- QCachegrind 0.7.4
- Windows 2012R2

Comment: Seems like `profilestats` may not be including the relevant data in its output. Have you tried saving the profiling output in the "Python format" and converting it using [`pyprof2calltree`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyprof2calltree/)?

Answer (score 1):

I second @taleniat comment. I am an OSX user. I was having some trouble getting qcachegrind to work so I ended up using pyprof2calltree and it works perfectly, source code tab included. YMMV.

First run your script with cProfile

`python -m cProfile -o report.profile report.py`

Then you can use pyprof2calltree to launch qcachegrind (no need for intermediate conversion).

`pyprof2calltree -k -i report.profile`

by the way, Python 2.7.10 and qcachegrind 0.7.4 installed via homebrew on OSX 10.11